# Fastest way to uniqify a list in Python

Tags: python, performance, list

Fastest way to uniqify a list in Python without preserving order? I saw many complicated solutions on the Internet - could they be faster than simply:

```
list(set([a,b,c,a]))
```

Comment: Why not benchmark them and find out?

Comment: Shoot, if you need unique, why bother converting back from a set?

Comment: 2Chris: So benchmarks done...
2Mike: Because list -> list

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
set([a, b, c, a])
```

Leave it in that form if possible.

Comment: You can iterate over sets and test for membership in sets, so converting back to list if you don't need order is unnecessary.

Comment: It is worth noting that this assumes that all the elements of the list are **hashable** (see the [Pyhon glossary](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html))

Comment: If element order is important in the original list (which I know the question says it is not, but it may be to some readers), this may destroy that order. pylang's answer provides an option that maintains order.

Answer (score 26):

Going to a set only works for lists such that all their items are *hashable* -- so e.g. in your example if `c = []`, the code you give will raise an exception.  For non-hashable, but comparable items, sorting the list, then using `itertools.groupby` to extract the unique items from it, is the best available solution (O(N log N)).  If items are neither all hashable, nor all comparable, your only "last ditch" solution is `O(N squared)`.

You can code a function to "uniquify" any list that uses the best available approach by trying each approach in order, with a `try`/`except` around the first and second (and a `return` of the result either at the end of the `try` clause, or, elegantly, in an `else` clause of the `try` statement;-).

Answer (score 6):

This [updated post](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/fastest-way-to-uniquify-a-list-in-python-3.6) by Peter Bengtsson suggests two of the fastest ways to make a list of unique items in Python 3.6+ are:

```
# Unordered (hashable items)
list(set(seq))

# Order preserving
list(dict.fromkeys(seq))
```